# Why does one question redirect to another, only slightly related, question?

Tags: support

After searching for an issue I was having, I found the following question linked;

[Filter out Configurable Products in layered navigation who have out of stock filtered option](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14451/filter-out-configurable-products-in-layered-navigation-who-have-out-of-stock-fil?lq=1)

However, clicking this just redirects me to;

[Layered navigation filters for grouped products only](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4743/layered-navigation-filters-for-grouped-products-only)

Which, while slightly related, doesn't answer the original question? The original is though listed on the right hand side under "Linked".

Answer (score 2):

The question [Filter out Configurable Products in layered navigation who have out of stock filtered option](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14451/filter-out-configurable-products-in-layered-navigation-who-have-out-of-stock-fil?lq=1) is marked as a duplicate for [Layered navigation filters for grouped products only](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4743/layered-navigation-filters-for-grouped-products-only) and it does not have any answers.
For me it does not redirect when logged in, but it redirects when not logged in.
If it redirects for you when logged in, it may have something to do with the privileges you have based on your reputation points.

Comment: You're right, in that the redirect only occurs when not logged in. I'd argue though that this isn't a duplicate, even if the fixes will be located around similar parts of similar files, the fact that the 2 users are asking different question is only ever going to leave people who aren't logged in confused. And what if I wanted to add an answer that would solve the Config stock issue directly? Because it won't be the same as one that fixes the grouped product issue.

Comment: I don't think we can control this redirect. If you want to add an answer for the original question just nominate it for reopen. I'm not sure if you have the privilege to do that. If you cannot nominate it for reopen and you have an answer, just say so. I will reopen it.